# Repetable, global Custom fields in Wordpress Theme

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-fields

quick question, what is the best approach in your opinion to make /parts files content editable to the user from the Wordpress admin?

1. myTheme:

   - parts

     - some-block.php ( hero banner in example with some short content )
   - templates

     - template-homepage.php  <-- get_template_part('parts/some', 'block' )
     - template-page.php  <-- get_template_part('parts/some', 'block' )

Usually if I have a section unique for certain page I am using Advanced Custom Fields to do the job, but I don't think it will be a good choice in this case.

I am looking for a clean solution that will allow Wordpress users globally define parts content from the administration panel.

Any tips?

Thanks in advance

List item

Comment: Look for WordPress templating plugins I suppose if the purpose if for users to edit the template parts on WordPress back-end.

Answer (score 0):

If you are an Advanced Custom Fields Pro plugin user the ACF Options page will do the job for you. Using it you can easily define section repetable across the whole theme: in ex. footer content or some CTA sections like signup for newsletter or etc.